# public data set in big query showing null values

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset

i uploaded a public dataset on google big query called nyccitibike and it had one table with values of all types and a second table with all null values. what could be the issue?

im still learning how to use sql, im in the process of doing a data analytics certification. I thought i needed to go back and upload it again or refresh the dataset. I dont know how to convert the values when there are no values at all. the whole data table is null.